# Writing in UnsafeMutablePointer in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

The code below was working in previous versions of Swift, now compiler rejects it.
I need this function to interop with Swift from ObjectiveC.

```
@objc public static func myFunc(jdUT: Double, _ lon: Double, _ lat: Double,
                                           _ dayLen: Double, _ SbhDeg: Double, _ MgrbDeg: Double,
                                           omsk: UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>)
    {
        var z = somefuncion()
        // this line gives this error : Cannot assign to property: 'omsk' is a 'let' constant
        omsk.memory=z;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message is misleading. The `memory` property of
`Unsafe(Mutable)Pointer` has been renamed to `pointee` in Swift 3:

```
let z = someFunction()
omsk.pointee = z
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@objc public static func myFunc(jdUT: Double, _ lon: Double, _ lat: Double,
                                       _ dayLen: Double, _ SbhDeg: Double, _ MgrbDeg: Double,
                                       inout omsk: UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>)
{
    var z = somefuncion()
    // this line gives this error : Cannot assign to property: 'omsk' is a 'let' constant
    omsk.memory=z;
}
```

Adding inout before the omsk parameter should work.